# Which Blackmagic codec to choose?

Tags: codec

I purchased recently a new BMPCC 4K and I'm facing a big problem with file sizes...

The files are tremendously huge, so I have to make a choice about the codec to choose.

I'm shooting basically nature documentary so I need to color-adjust my files in editing, but I do not do any green screen or heavy special effects.

BlackMagic provides several codecs and I do not want to compromise quality, but without going into crazy unnoticeable quality...

I'm thinking of choosing Blackmagic Raw 8:1. Does any one know the technical differences between those codecs (beside the file size which varies quite a lots) ? Blackmagic Raw 3:1, 5:1, 8:1, 12:1, ProRes 422HQ, ProRes 422, ProRes 422 LT, ProRes 422 Proxy

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Braw Constant Quality Q5.

With 21-58MB/s it is on the lower end of data consumption while still giving you RAW capability.

BRAW gives you the RAW capabilities like Blackmagic Highlight recovery, changing the ISO, lossless color temperature changing. And 12bit colors.

ProRes gives you higher compatibility (Braw is currently only supported by Resolve) and "only" has 10bit Color.